# スタックオーバフローで数式を利用する場合はどのようにしたらいいですか

Tags: サポート

[初速・最終速度・移動時間・移動距離が決まっている状況で、速度をスムーズに変化させる](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/16322/%E5%88%9D%E9%80%9F-%E6%9C%80%E7%B5%82%E9%80%9F%E5%BA%A6-%E7%A7%BB%E5%8B%95%E6%99%82%E9%96%93-%E7%A7%BB%E5%8B%95%E8%B7%9D%E9%9B%A2%E3%81%8C%E6%B1%BA%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E7%8A%B6%E6%B3%81%E3%81%A7-%E9%80%9F%E5%BA%A6%E3%82%92%E3%82%B9%E3%83%A0%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA%E3%81%AB%E5%A4%89%E5%8C%96%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B) の回答を見ました。

スタックオーバフローで数式を質問または回答で利用する場合はどのようにしたらいいですか。

Answer (score 4):

[Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) では MathJax によって LaTeX の記法を受け付けるようですが、ja には現時点では適用されていないようですね。

現状では自作するなり外部のサービスを利用するなりして、何らかの方法で画像で貼り付けるしかないと思います（事例：[アルゴリズム - 既にある平均値を更新し続けるアルゴリズムを教えてください。 - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/14964/%e6%97%a2%e3%81%ab%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b%e5%b9%b3%e5%9d%87%e5%80%a4%e3%82%92%e6%9b%b4%e6%96%b0%e3%81%97%e7%b6%9a%e3%81%91%e3%82%8b%e3%82%a2%e3%83%ab%e3%82%b4%e3%83%aa%e3%82%ba%e3%83%a0%e3%82%92%e6%95%99%e3%81%88%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8f%e3%81%a0%e3%81%95%e3%81%84)）。

必要なら ja でも LaTex 記法を受け付けるように機能追加を要望した方がいいかもしれません。

Comment: 一昨年の話なので今はわかりませんが、[本家SOでMathJaxをサポートしていないのはパフォーマンス上の理由から](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252282/2818869)だそうです。複雑な数式を一つだけ表示したい等であれば、 [スニペット機能でMathJaxを使ったHTMLを埋め込む](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283127/2818869) という荒業も。